# Upgraded to Null Safety but recieving 'map' isn't defined

Tags: flutter

I have upgraded my Flutter Project to Null Safety. Fixed all the errors bar this one.

The method 'map' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'map'.

Any help would be great!

```
SliverToBoxAdapter(
              child: StreamBuilder(
                stream: _latestNoteCache.noteStream,
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data != null) {

                    List<Widget> widgets = snapshot.data!.map<Widget>((e) {
                      return Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(32, 10, 32, 0),
                        child: AutomaticNoteCard(note: e),
                      );
                    }).toList();
                    widgets = widgets.sublist(0, min(widgets.length, 5));
                    return Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 16),
                      child: Column(
                        children: widgets,
                      ),
                    );
                  } else {
                    return Container();
                  }
                },
              ),
            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you have not defined the type of data for your stream builder.

Something like this :

```dart
StreamBuilder<List<Widget>>(
                stream: _latestNoteCache.noteStream,
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data != null) {

                    List<Widget> widgets = snapshot.data!.map<Widget>((e) {
```

Follow this official documentation for more detail:
[StreamBuilder class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html)

Comment: When I add that in next to Streambuilder I get this.

The named parameter 'builder' is required, but there's no corresponding argument.
Try adding the required argument.

Comment: I gave example like you have to add the data type In your code. I edited the answer.